# Values of BsonDocument missing when PutAsync over web request?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, controller, bson

I am trying to send a simple BsonDocument to WebAPI through PutAsync request.

However, the values of the BsonDocument **missing** when passed to the WebAPI Controller.

Here are the codes of my client.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendBdoc()
{
    try
    {
       var abc = new BsonDocument("Abc","hoho");

       var bformatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();

       var id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

       HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58836");

       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

       var response = await client.PutAsync($"api/query/{id}", abc, bformatter);

       return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Here are the codes of my controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, BsonDocument doc)
{
     try
     {
            //MongoDB Connection stuff here

            var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));

            var update = collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, doc, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
            var result = await update;

            if (result.IsAcknowledged)
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            return NotFound();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return InternalServerError();
     }
}
```

Screenshot of debugging my **client app**, variable abc is filled with value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/txp8l.png

Screenshot of debugging at **web controller side**, value of the BsonDocument turned null now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBTe3.png

Do i overlook something? Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It could be a limitation of the default model binder.
Could you try to remove the "string id" from the Put method and resend the request?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. But the "string id" was needed because i used that as my route attribute. Sorry that i forgot to include in my code snippet in my Controller part.

[Route("{id}"]

Comment: Could you try to decorate the Put method parameters?
Something like
Put([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody]BsonDocument doc)
to give a model binder a hint where to parse a data from.